# Less Mixin for "background-position" to isolate x and y values

Tags: css, background, less, css-sprites

I'm using a custom radio button spritesheet for an application that I'm writing for my work. I've split up this spritesheet logically into columns and rows - the columns and rows correspond with specific states that the radio button can have. (The columns are states, such as disabled, and application states, such as "correct" or "incorrect", while the rows are for selected states and hover/focus states.

My implementation uses dynamically-added semantic classes to influence the background position. As such, if a radiobutton is marked "correct" and it has focus, a "correct" CSS class will be applied and a "focus" class will be applied, calling the background position for the column and row respectively.

For these classes, I'm currently using the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` CSS attributes, which work in IE and chrome, but not in Firefox and Opera. (These two properties aren't officially part of any CSS spec.) Since we're using the LESS preprocessor, I want to know if there's a way to create a LESS mixin that will dynamically "inherit" an x or y value for the "background-position" property.

In psuedocode, something like this:

```
.my-background-mixin-x(@value) {
   background-position: @value + 'px', inherit; (inherit y-value)
}

.my-background-mixin-y(@value) {
   background-position: inherit, @value + 'px'; (inherit x-value)
}
```

(That's not really accurate syntax, but I hope it conveys the idea.)

Is this possible in LESS? Can less store variables and target properties like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have LESS `inherit` values that way, and `background-position` itself can only `inherit` both values in the CSS cascade. I think a possible "easy" solution would be the following code. Note: Since I do not know your sprite positioning, for the sake of illustration here, I have *assumed* the following:

1. Your columns are 10px wide and are in the order of a) a "base" image, b) your `disabled`  image, c) your `.correct` image, and d) your `.incorrect` image.
2. Your rows are 10px tall and are in the order of a) a "base" image, and b) your hover and `.focus` image (which are the same in my example; not sure about your real situation).
3. That your "base" and `disabled` settings do not require a `:hover` or `.focus` value.

Given those assumptions, then using a mixin with a horizontal (X) and vertical (Y) shift amount, with a passed in multiplier for the column and row position in the sprite, can give us this code (which you should be able to modify in such places where my assumptions were wrong):

**LESS Code**

```css
input[type=radio] {
   // bkg position set mixin
   .setBkgPos(@X: 0, @Y: 0) {
      @Xshift: -10px;
      @Yshift: -10px;
      background-position: (@Xshift * @X) (@Yshift * @Y);
   }
   .setBkgPos;

   &[disabled="disabled"] {
      .setBkgPos(1, 0);
   }    

   &.correct {
      .setBkgPos(2, 0);
      &:hover, &.focus {
         .setBkgPos(2, 1);
      }
   }

   &.incorrect {
      .setBkgPos(3, 0);
      &:hover, &.focus {
         .setBkgPos(3, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

**CSS Example Output**

```css
input[type=radio] {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
input[type=radio][disabled="disabled"] {
  background-position: -10px 0px;
}
input[type=radio].correct {
  background-position: -20px 0px;
}
input[type=radio].correct:hover,
input[type=radio].correct.focus {
  background-position: -20px -10px;
}
input[type=radio].incorrect {
  background-position: -30px 0px;
}
input[type=radio].incorrect:hover,
input[type=radio].incorrect.focus {
  background-position: -30px -10px;
}
```

Comment: Heyyyy....that's clever! I see what you did there, using the subclasses. It's not truly ideal (from a theoretical perspective) but your assumptions were correct, so this should work. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: I just remembered why I didn't do this - the hover states and focus states are handled by jQuery in my solution, and the radio buttons are swapped for divs with a background property. Still, I'll see if it's possible to figure this out. It may be possible to dynamically set element states through javascript.

Comment: @lunchmeat317--my solution was making a lot of assumptions about your code, as I did not have any of your code to go by. However, you can easily change `:hover` to a class `.hover` to control with jQuery, and certainly have the `input[type=radio]` change to whatever indicates your `div` you are using for a "radio" button. The selectors are not so much what is important as the way they build and "override" one another to get your background positioning where you want it when you want it.